# Can I plot a diagonal plotline in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have a diagonal plotline in highcharts?

I have a line chart which tracks weightloss (y axis = weight, x axis = time), and I need a plotline which starts at the initial weight, and plots diagonally to the time when the user should have lost the weight by.

I can plot a simply flat plotline like this:

```
plotLines: [{
            value: 0.696,
            width: 3,
            color: 'red',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            label: {
                text: 'Latest value',
                align: 'right',
                y: 5,
                x: 0
            }
        }]
```

but, that's just a simple flat line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to simply use a separate line series.

Plot just your first and last point.  You can disable markers, turn off mousetracking, and hide from the legend if you want it to behave just like a plotLine.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.enabled

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.showInLegend

Answer (score 2):

Plotlines can be horizontal or vertical, but you can use renderer to add custom line (like diagonal) in the chart: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path()

Comment: Yes, but what is a good way to have a given line width for any angle?

Comment: Hi @BSeven! For setting line width, try to use SVG attributes `stroke-width`. To have different line colors for the angles, you can build a line from several rendered paths as in the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lxruq2hv/).